# PHP rand function (or not so rand)

Tags: php, random

I was testing PHP rand function to write on a image. Of course the output shows that it's not so random. The code I used:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$lenght = 512;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($lenght, $lenght);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 255);
for ($y = 0; $y < $lenght; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
        if (rand(0,1) == 0) {
            imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $blue);
        }
    }
}       
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

My question is, if I use image width/lenght (variable $lenght in this example) number like 512, 256 or 1024, it is very clear that it's not so random. When I change the variable to 513 for an example, it is so much harder for human eye to detect it. Why is that? What is so special about these numbers?

512:

[image: 512 pixels]

513:

[image: 513 pixels]

**Edit: I'm running xampp on Windows to test it.**

Comment: http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif

Comment: These images answer a question "why a randomness test suite runs so long?" Well, because order is visible in some patterns, but not other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug which isn't related to PHP, but inherant to the windows API used by PHP. The random function of this API is very bad.

This problem will not exist on Linux or MacOS (or any other system).

You can learn more about this here: http://cod.ifies.com/2008/05/php-rand01-on-windows-openssl-rand-on.html

If it is more visible with some value, this is mostly because of the dimensions of the image, and the clear lines formed by the pattern. This is definitively linked to our perception, some patterns looks more random than others.

The human brain random function is very buggy. What we see as random or not isn't reliable at all. This is a known phenomenon but off topic here.

Comment: Windows doesn't provide a `random`. I believe MSVC++ provides a macro for it that points at the CRT's `rand` though. Windows *does* provide OpenSSL-style random number generators (`CryptGenRandom` and friends), but PHP does not use them.

Comment: @BillyONeal, that is right. I should have said, that standard rand function in C provided by MSVCRT is bugguy. That was an oversimplification and I never meant that generate random number on windows was impossible.

Comment: It's not buggy. It's essentially the same `rand` provided by glibc (also an LCG) and pretty much every C implementation I've ever heard of. The C standard never said that the `rand` provided had to be cryptographically secure. (If nothing else, making such requirements on small microcontrollers would be hard) Linear congruential generators have the advantage that they require very little space to maintain state -- typically `sizeof(int)`. There are better generators in terms of randomness but they require a ton more space. Mersenne Twister, for instance is typically `624*sizeof(int)`.